# no Layout named ContactPointEmail-Contact Point Email Layout found - Spring20 sandbox

Tags: deployment, spring-20

We are getting the following error

> no Layout named ContactPointEmail-Contact Point Email Layout found

when we are deploying the changeset from QA org to UAT org. We went more into the details and found that there are a couple of new standard objects(At least for me) Contact Point Email and Contact Point Phone are there in the QA sandbox which is not present in the UAT sandbox. As we are sending profiles also along with the components profiles are looking for these objects page layouts and they are not available in the UAT org. This is what causes the issue.

**Do you guys have any idea why they are not there and if we need to enable them from where we can enable?** I read in the Salesforce article these objects are not available in all the organizations so I logged a case with Salesforce. I appreciate it [image]if anyone can help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Also put a case in. Here's their response

> Salesforce Licensing and Provisioning is working with a new rollout tool that is experiencing issues. They are currently working through the problems but don't yet have a date for when sandboxes will be updated.

Their suggested workaround was to do either:

1. Refresh the sandbox org

or

2. Use the [License Match tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335272&type=1&mode=1) to trigger a fresh license copy from the source org which will apply the license set from the source org of the sandbox and trigger aggregation that way.

**Option 2 worked well** if you're unable to refresh your sandbox. It brings over the objects and layouts so that you should be able to do your deployments without those invalid references.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options as workarounds to allow you to move your changes:

1. You can try editing the concerned profiles and change the
   layout assignment and restrict only to the ones which are present in
   your UAT org.
2. You can edit the profile XML using an IDE and see if it
   gets deployed along with your deployment package.
3. You can reach out to Salesforce support and check if they
   can help remove references in your QA org for these new set of
   objects at profile level and help you deploy.

Comment: While this may be a workaround, it doesn't really answer his question which is regarding why those consent management objects are not in one sandbox (but in the other) and whether there's a way to enable them.