# Objects without layouts on some orgs

Tags: page-layout, metadata, sobject

Several not long ago created org DO have these objects with layouts:

Example: Authorization Form -> Authorization Form Layout, Data Use Legal Basis -> Data Use Legal Basis Layout.

However, some orgs just have these objects without any related layouts.

How is it possible? When should I expect those orgs to be updated?

**UPDATE**

Also several objects do not even exist in some orgs:

Example: Invoice Line, Invoice.

Comment: Summer '19 released these new objects as part of their [Data Protection and Privacy](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_data_protection_and_privacy.htm). It's possible there were issues with the rollout to developer orgs depending on when you refershed/created. I have had issues with mismatches in what object layouts exist between different sandboxes related to these objects as noted in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294719/no-layout-named-contactpointemail-contact-point-email-layout-found-spring20-sa/295811#295811)

Comment: @KrisGoncalves This would be helpful if I had sandboxes. However, the problem is that I have not updated org (from which I create manage package) and clients with new orgs that do have these layouts, but my package just do not see them. However, when I copy package code to the org in place, it does work perfectly and see everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to API version with which I made callouts to Metadata API. I have upgraded request URIs with higher version and layouts showed up for me.